# Ordered Complex plane?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are there any (non-trivial) fields out there with a relation $>$ satisfying

$$(x>y, y>z)\Rightarrow x>z\hspace{5mm}\forall x,y,z$$

$$x\not>x\hspace{5mm}\forall x$$

$$x>y\Rightarrow y\not>x\hspace{5mm}\forall x,y$$

$$(x\not>y, y\not>x)\Rightarrow x=y\hspace{5mm}\forall x,y$$

$$x>y\Rightarrow x+z>y+z\hspace{5mm}\forall x,y,z$$

defined over it, in which the equation $X^2+1=0$ has a solution?

Comment: Sure: Take $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$ with lex order. Multiplication isn't going to be compatible with the ordering, though.

Comment: A total order, compatible with the field operations?

Comment: (Note that no such field can satisfy, e.g., "For all $a$ we have either $x\gt y\implies ax\gt ay$ for all $x,y$ or $x\gt y\implies ay\gt ax$ for all $x,y$" along with the natural expected relations; this is a nice exercise. Hint: take $a=i$ (where $i$ is any element $X$ satisfying your equation $X^2+1=0$), and try and apply this twice.)

Comment: The second answer won't satisfy the fourth condition. (Steven Stadnicki)

Comment: I don't need the order to be compatible with multiplication. (S. Stadnicki)

Comment: In that case, anomaly's comment still answers the question. (And note that my initial comment came before the question was edited. :P )

Comment: lex order does the job! Thanks!